# Rails has_many_through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many :through relationship between three models in my app:

- User
- Question
- Answer

I've used the [Active Record Associations docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) to establish the relationships.

User.rb

```
has_many :answers
has_many :questions, through: :answers
```

Question.rb

```
has_many :answers
has_many :users, through: :answers
```

Answer.rb

```
belongs_to :question
belongs_to :user
```

This appears to be working.

```
User.find(1).questions
User.find(1).answers
```

Both of the above methods return exactly what I expect them to. However, what I need is to return the Question and Answer as a pair.

How do I say: "Ok, get all of the questions that the current_user has answered, and return the answer along with it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this to the controller:

```
@questions = Question.joins(:answers).where(answers: { id: current_user.answers.pluck(:id) })
```

And then in your view, for each question, you get the answer like this:

```
- @questions.each do |question|
  - answers = question.answers.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

You can (and should) always move part of the code to the models as scopes.

Comment: Perfect! I'm using the following in my view: http://pastebin.com/z9s6mq3m and it's displaying just as I want. Thanks!